# Visual Studio 2013 - Debug -> Start New Instance

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a windows forms project and I would want to be able to start debugging 10 instances of that project at once.

When you normally debug a project you start only one instance. You can create additional ones by going to Debug -> Start New Instance.

Is it possible in Visual Studio to add a shortcut or a button or something that will be like: `Debug 10 Instances`  and pop-up 10 instances of that project.

Comment: you can start a batch-command that starts multiple instances of your project, or is that not what you want?

Comment: with "start" I meant the `project-properties / Debug / Start external program` setting

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the VS2013 menu you can go to Tools -> Options and then Environment->Keyboard.

Search for the `"ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Debug.Startnewinstance"` command and map it to any shortcut you like.

Obviously, this starts a new instance everytime you hit the keyboard shortcut. If you don't want to do this 10 times every time you want to start debugging your project, the next step is to [create an Add-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80493a3w.aspx).

You can then [bind a command to multiple keyboard shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228766.aspx), or in your case to the same keyboard shortcut 10 times.

Edit: You are right. Add-ins are indeed deprecated in Visual Studio 2013, but they *do* still work though. I have Visual Studio 2013 with the [Visual Studio 2013 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40758) installed and under Other Project Types -> Extensibility I can create a new Visual Studio Add-in Project. Try it.

Comment: According with the same description, `Visual Studio add-ins are deprecated in Visual Studio 2013. You should upgrade your add-ins to VSPackage extensions. For more information about upgrading.`

Comment: Thanks, switching F5 from Debug.Start to StartNewInstance means it only builds stuff that the current project depends on, rather than everything in the solution, which saves a lot of time.